# CMake Xcode generator with alternative toolchains

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, build, homebrew

I'm running macOS Ventura with Xcode 14.2. I've used `brew` to install `llvm` so I have `clang-15` and `clang++-15`.  This is all in working order, and `clang` points to the homebrew version.

The homebrew version of LLVM comes with an Xcode toolchain file `LLVM15.0.7.xctoolchain` which I've placed in `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains`.  When I launch Xcode, I can see the `org.llvm.15.0.7` toolchain and I can successfully use it.

Now, I have a `cmake` project and I'm using `-G Xcode` to generate an Xcode project instead of Unix makefiles (`cmake` to make Unix makefiles with llvm from Homebrew works and the project compiles).  However, I need my generator to use the Homebrew LLVM version (i.e., the toolchain `org.llvm.15.0.7` which I have installed, as opposed to the default Xcode toolchain).

I cannot get `cmake -G Xcode -T "org.llvm.15.0.7"` to generate an Xcode project using the alternative toolchain, and it keeps defaulting to the default Xcode toolchain.

I've also tried setting various environment variables in my CMakeLists.txt file (`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET`, `CMAKE_XCODE_PLATFORM_TOOLSET`), to no avail.

I've read the cmake documentation, which suggests this is possible but the docs are not very helpful: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Xcode.html#generator:Xcode

I have also set the environment variable `TOOLCHAINS` to `org.llvm.15.0.7` and `xcodebuild` successfully picks this up when invoked from the command line (separately, and outside of `cmake`), but this is not picked up by the `cmake` generator.

Has anyone managed to get this to work, and if so, how?

Comment: To the person who close-voted and other curators, I don't see how this is not about software development. It's about software development tools. As far as I can tell, this question is on-topic.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this however I need an older version of the toolchain. You helped me in your description so I will try some things you did and maybe we can solve this together.

Comment: Have not found a solution. For now, what I've done is use UNIX makefiles and manually create the Xcode project / targets using the external build option. Once that is done, Xcode debugging and compilation works fine.  Not ideal, but works for now.